# Save custom user meta on registration

Tags: custom-field, user-meta, user-registration

I'm trying to create my own registration form and adding phone number as required field and I would love to save that phone number as custom user meta.

After validation and santizing inputs, ets. my code looks like this:

```
// this returns the correct value etc. - string(9) "126777889"
var_dump($metas['user_phone'])

$user_id = wp_insert_user($fields);
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_phone', $metas['user_phone'] );
```

The user is created correctly, but there is something wrong with the phone meta field - in backend it looks like this:
[image]

I also tried this approach to test whether the meta exists:

```
if(get_user_meta($user_id,'user_phone')) {
    update_user_meta($user_id,'user_phone');
} else {
    add_user_meta($user_id,'user_phone');    
}
```

Also tried to add the meta with 'user_register' action like this:

```
function addMyCustomMeta($user_id,$meta) {
    update_user_meta($user_id,$meta);
}
add_action('user_register','addMyCustomMeta',10,2,);
```

And then using like this:

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user($fields);
do_action('addMyCustomMeta',$user_id,$metas['user_phone']);
```

In all cases I end up with the situation described in the picture above.
No meta title and the value is saved as multiple "Array"

In database it looks fine:

[image]

Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: How do you print the values in your HTML code? Sharing your html code would be useful.

Comment: Here is complete code: https://gist.github.com/cafesk8/78e7ac3555aa94afcb35d815853c4365

HTML only:
https://gist.github.com/cafesk8/5503fb9c49295c13f8d4c26d3ffcc2e6

Answer (score 9):

You have to trigger the following hooks:

- [user_register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)
- [personal_options_update](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options_update)
- [edit_user_profile_update](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update)

  ```
  add_action('user_register', 'addMyCustomMeta');    
  add_action('personal_options_update', 'addMyCustomMeta' );    
  add_action('edit_user_profile_update','addMyCustomMeta' );    
  function addMyCustomMeta( $user_id ) {    
             update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_phone', $_POST['user_phone'] ); 
  }
  ```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: In what part of my code should I add the actions? I want to trigger that only if all values and metas are valid, etc. See: http://gist.github.com/cafesk8/78e7ac3555aa94afcb35d815853c4365